# System.DmlException: Update failed. when running test class

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

I am creating a test class and receive the following error when running the test.

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0012o00002WUpPFAA1; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Name]: [Name]

The Exception is from the last line in bold update acc;

I am also only getting 75% coverage so maybe I am not testing update correctly. Nothing inside of the if != null is covered.

How can I correct these problems and get 100% coverage?

Part of class with no coverage

```
    if(response.getStatusCode()==200){
        // Map the response to variables
        Map<String,Object> results=(Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
            acc.Name=String.valueOf(results.get('Test'));
            acc.NumberOfEmployees=Integer.valueOf(results.get('Test'));
        Map<String,Object> mainresults=(Map<String,Object>)(results.get('Test'));
            if (results.get('Test') != Null){
                acc.Shippingcountry=String.valueOf(mainresults.get('Test'));
                acc.Shippingcity=String.valueOf(mainresults.get('Test'));
                acc.Shippingpostalcode=String.valueOf(mainresults.get('Test'));
                acc.Shippingstreet=String.valueOf(mainresults.get('Test')).removeStart('(').removeEnd(')');              
            } 
        Map<String,Object> nextresults=(Map<String,Object>)(results.get('Test'));
            //Check for null results before mapping
            if (results.get('Test') != Null){
                acc.Billingcountry=String.valueOf(nextresults.get('Test'));
                acc.Billingcity=String.valueOf(nextresults.get('Test'));
                acc.Billingpostalcode=String.valueOf(nextresults.get('Test'));
                acc.Billingstreet=String.valueOf(nextresults.get('Test')).removeStart('(').removeEnd(')');
            }

            acc.ast_updated__c = system.now();
            acc.Success__c = true;
            acc.Sync_Error__c = null;
            // Make the update .
            **update acc;**
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
private class Test {

    @isTest 
    public static void makeCalloutTest() {


        Account acc = new Account ();
        acc.Name = 'Test Account';
        acc.VAT__c = '920293849';
        insert acc;


        Test.startTest();
        String responseObj = '{"Name": "Test", "Employees": "150", "ErrorInfo": {}}';
        CalloutMock fakeResponse = new CalloutMock(200, 'OK', responseObj, null);
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, fakeResponse);
        MyClass.makeCallout(new set<id> {acc.Id});   
        Test.stopTest();

     }    

    @isTest 
    public static void makeCalloutFailTest() {


        Account acc = new Account ();
        acc.Name = 'Test Account';
        acc.VAT__c = '920293849';
        insert acc;


        Test.startTest();
        String responseObj = '{{}}';
        BregCalloutMock fakeResponse = new 
        BregCalloutMock(404, 'Not Found', responseObj, null);
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, fakeResponse);
        BregV3.makeCallout(new set<id> {acc.Id});

        acc.Sync__c = string.valueOf(fakeResponse);
        acc.success= false;
        Test.stopTest();


     }    

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a coverage problem; it's a logic problem. Your test is *failing*, and you only get coverage for tests that pass.

It appears to me on a quick read that your problem is the JSON with which you seed your Mock does not match your code's expectations. You are setting the required field `Account.Name` via

```
        acc.Name=String.valueOf(results.get('Test'));
```

That property is not present in your JSON, so you're in effect setting that required field to `null`.